# Netty Encoding/Decoding Java Object

Tags: java, serialization, netty

I am using Netty 3.9. I have a simple client server setup which I got from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_%28software%29#Netty_TCP_Example.  I have expanded the example to send a Java search plan object from the client to the server

The search plan object is a 3rd party object which has methods for serializing and deserializing.  Serialization writes the object into a byte[] array.  My client pipeline factory looks like this:

```
this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                    new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                    new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
                            ALLOWED_CHARACTER_BUFFER_SIZE, Delimiters
                                    .lineDelimiter()),

                    /* We also add our Clients own ChannelHandler. */
                    new ClientChannelHandler());
        }
    });
```

I think StringDecoder and StringEncoder are incorrect.  I think I need some sort of ByteEncoder/Decoder which I do not see.  Do I need to write these?  I tried this code to convert to a String on the Client

```
 byte[] byteVersion = searchPlanRepo.serialize(missionNum);  // serialize the search plan
 searchPlanStr = new String(byteVersion, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

but on the server no matter what I do to "deserialize" the object I fail.  I continuously get the error message:

"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to payload.mission.SearchPlanType"

My questions:

1. Do I need a custom byte encoder/decoder?  Are there any examples?
2. Serialization seems simple:  byte array to String but deserialization from a String to a byte array does not work.  I am sure I am missing something.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks for taking the time to read this. :)

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look to the serialization codec:

http://netty.io/3.9/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/serialization/package-summary.html

As to the associated example:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.9/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/objectecho

They illustrate how you can serialize/deserialize objects. Of course you can also write your own codec if it is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the sample ObjectDecoder and ObjectEncoder examples and this solved my problem.  I changed the pipeline code on the client and I can now send out my missions.  Here is the code from the client/sender:

```
this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                    new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers
                            .cacheDisabled(getClass().getClassLoader())),
                    new ClientChannelHandler());
        }
    });
```

The pipelineFactory code on the server/receiver is nearly identical.  The only difference is the handler for each side.  The client uses ClientChannelHandler which simply logs a message from the Server.  The server uses a ServerChannelHandler which takes the received mission and casts it to the correct Java type so I can manipulate it.